# window.scroll does not work for "home" key and "#" link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple (and long) script to change colors in my navigation bar according to what is on screen. Everything works perfectly fine but not when "home" keyboard is pressed or when "#" link is clicked. My script is like this:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
 var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

 var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
 var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

 return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
 && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );}

$(window).scroll(function () {
       isOnScreen = isScrolledIntoView("#second-div");
       isOnTopPage = isScrolledIntoView("#first-div");
       if(isOnScreen){
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "black")
          });
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "white")
          });          
       }
       if(isOnTopPage){
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "blue")
          });
          $(".navbar .navbar-collapse > ul > li > a.item").mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).css("color", "white")
          });          
       }
});
```

Here, I posted only part of my long script, where "first-div" is the top of the webpage. What is happening is that, when user scrolls up and down using the scroll bar of the browser, or the arrow keys, it works fine. But when user clicks on the logo (linked to "#") or presses the button "Home", it does not. For instance, if the user was on the fifth div and pressed "Home", it would behave as if user was still on fifth div. 
Any hint? Is the problem on `window.scroll`? Going "home" is not considered scroll event? How should I deal with that?

EDIT: I found out that the only browser where it works with no problem is Safari. Chrome, Firefox and IE (latest version of all of them) give me trouble.

EDIT/SOLUTION: After @petkopalko mention a possible problem in the function, I realized that the problem was the size of the div. I changed the script to check if a specific and smaller element inside top div was on screen. Now it works.

Comment: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ872/1/) shows the scroll firing on both home key press and link click. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but somehow I don't see anything. Nothing was logged in the console in any browser, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.scroll is fired even on # link, or home key, check the jsfiddle in comment, maybe is something wrong with your isScrolledIntoView function - I do not checked, but I think its better use some ready made solutions:

If you use bootstrap you can use [scrollspy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).

If you do not use bootstrap you can use [minimalistic scroll spy](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/). Or try google scrollspy.

```
some code for SO to post this answer with jsfiddle
```

Comment: I did not use ready made solutions because sometimes it is a lot more work to edit them (I used 'color' changes in my example to make it simple and short, but I am dealing with shapes in my real script). But because of your comment, I checked the isScrolledIntoView and I realized that the problem was the size of the div. Sometimes it would not be fully "into view" (in Safari it was because of the smaller height of the bookmarks bar...). So, I changed the script to check if a specific element was on screen. Now it works. So, thanks for pointing out that the problem could be there.